# Opening AWS ports for inbound traffic?

Tags: amazon-ec2, geoportal

I am configuring an instance of Geoportal Server on an Amazon EC2 instance.  I have ports 8080 open for tomcat, but need to open ports for Apache Directory Studio.

How do I view ports which are accessible for inbound traffic?

Answer (score 4):

In your AWS console, look for "Security Groups" on the left. Find out which security groups your instance is already using, and/or create a new one for the port you need to open. Add a new inbound rule to that security group for TCP and the 0.0.0.0/0 source. If you created a new security group for this, add it to your instance.

You may need to also check that your instance itself doesn't run another firewall by itself. If it does, you'll need to open the required port there, too.